# A library for MySQL reserved and operator words and phrases

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know of a way or site that has a tool for searching MySQL reserved and query words and phrases w/ documentation for each? (please read on I've been to the manual)

For example, I am trying to find an explanation in detail for the "ON" operator for MySQL, and I cannot search it in the manual or anywhere else w/out getting tons of unrelated results.

Comment: fwiw, an explanation of the usage of `ON` is available under the [MySQL `JOIN` reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: Mark E, thanks for the note. I took a gander through the JOIN reference and found pretty much what I was looking for: "Generally, you should use the ON clause for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the WHERE clause to restrict which rows you want in the result set." Example, "SELECT left_tbl.*
  FROM left_tbl LEFT JOIN right_tbl ON left_tbl.id = right_tbl.id
  WHERE right_tbl.id IS NULL;"

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you want to know about short keywords you can use the following translation list and google on the related keyword:

```
keyword*related to*relevant MySQL manual page
---------------------------------------------------
ON      JOIN       http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html
AS      SELECT     http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html
AS      ALIAS      http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html
AND     WHERE      http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/where-optimizations.html
OR      WHERE
XOR     WHERE
IN      COMPARISON http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html
LIKE    COMPARISON
IS      COMPARISON
BY      ORDER BY   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html
INTO    INSERT     http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html  (common)
INTO    SELECT     http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html  (rare)
```